# How to simply add pages without bogging down routes? (express.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, pug

I am working on a site with Express.js, and like it very much. I have it operating stably, but would like users to be able to add pages to the site (via a form, where it will have set fields, or via uploading a jade file). Preferably I would also like a moderation queue. Failing this, how can I add pages without having to add an entry to index.js for the route every time? If I add lots of pages, won't this make it slow?
Sorry for the wall of questions, and thanks in advance for any help!

EDIT: It's been requested that I narrow the query, so here goes:
I would like to add a web interface to Express.js that allows users to fill in a form and add a page to the website under a certain path. I would like a sort of "moderation queue" where I approve pages before they go live. I cannot find any sort of information on this use case. How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Please narrow down the specific issue you are facing. Questions asking for guides and the like are not appropriate questions. See [How do I ask a good question?
](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Narrowed down the scope of the question. Let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First and foremost, you will need to get yourself a database where the moderation queue can sit and wait to be processed. The specific methodology of how to structure this database, and how to integrate this data into pages that can be delivered will depend on your choice of database and view engine.

After you have set up this system, you can use express's route parameters so that you do not have to write out all the possible routes into your scripts. Your express app can take the route parameters, look up the relevant data in your database, integrate this into a page using your view engine, and have express deliver this page to your client.

[I would recommend giving express's guide on routing a thorough read](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html) as well as doing some more research into databases, and view engines.